# UICollectionView and core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview

Here i am using core data with UICollectionView and here is some problem happen whenever i reload CollectionView.

The problem is that when i create an album and set on it a latest photo(if any photo is exist other wise no setting for image on album) which is getting from entity "PHOTO" then reload collection view then this album also set an image on its self (an album is actually a CollectionViewCell).

Its really irritating. If any one can solve this Problem then kindly guide me.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    //Get Album Names
    GMSAlbum *objAlbumEntity = [arrayAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"AlbumName = %@",objAlbumEntity.name);

    delegate->currentAlbum = [arrayAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"current path = %@",delegate->currentAlbum);
    //Get Last image


    NSString *imagePath = [self getLastImage:delegate->currentAlbum];
    NSLog(@"Image Path = %@",imagePath);
    if (![imagePath isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIImageView *imageThumb = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                   CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        [imageThumb setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
        [cell addSubview:imageThumb];

    }

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)getLastImage:(Album *)album{

    NSString *imagePath = @"";
    GMSPhotoModel *objPhotoModel = [[GMSPhotoModel alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *arryPhotos = [objPhotoModel getAllPhotoForAlbum:album];
    NSLog(@"Array count = %d",[arryPhotos count]);

    if ([arryPhotos count]) {

        GMSPhoto *objPhotoName = [arryPhotos lastObject];
        imagePath = objPhotoName.path;
        NSLog(@"Naming Album = %@",objPhotoName.name);
    }

    NSLog(@"Path = %@",imagePath);
    return imagePath;
}
```

Comment: Tell your requirement...you are not clear...

Comment: why album set an image while having no photo in album when reload data

Comment: What you are getting from Viewing/Editing MS Word documents on iPad if there is no image ?

Comment: nothing image path is empty when i get photo with the related album but seems an image on a cell note every time happen but happen :(

Comment: Is it going inside the if condition?

Comment: no when photo path get empty string then no go inside the if condition

Comment: This should not happen then...make imageThumb = nil in else condition

Comment: the result is remain same sir

Answer (score 0):

Your UICollectionViewCell is reused (`[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]`). Thats why it show wrong album picture (Actually, its image from last album). To avoid this try clear  image if there no image path for current album:

```
    if (![imagePath isEqualToString:@""]) {
            UIImageView *imageThumb = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                       CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
            [imageThumb setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
            [cell addSubview:imageThumb];

        }
    else
    {
            [imageThumb setImage:nil];

}
```